# What brush tool in "PhotoImpact 8" would help me change brightness of some areas of the image?

Tags: brightness, brushes

I wonder if there is any such tool in "PhotoImpact 8" that would be somewhat similar to a brush that, if I move it over a certain area of my image (picture), would change that area's brightness.

If You know such function (I am sure there should be such one there), please give me some directions how to get to that kind of tool (the thing is I am using a Chinese computer at the moment and Chinese "PhotoImpact 8", so all the menus are in Chinese characters).

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to install new software? If so, you're almost certainly going to benefit from moving to a more recent program such as http://www.gimp.org.  I know this doesn't directly help, but it's just something to consider.

Comment: @chills42: Thank You, chills42, for this suggestion. I will install it, but...could You, please, direct me as to where in "gimp" I could find that kind of tool?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with "PhotoImpact 8", but in Gimp this is relatively easy.

Using Gimp the simplest method is to use the burn/dodge tool to paint over the area. It is best to do this using an overlay layer so that you can easily revert back if you make a mistake.

There is a tutorial using [this method on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT_tTDaYEOU).

Another way is to use [layer](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-dialog) masks and [dodge/burn/lighten/darken layers](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) to do the adjustment. This is a more powerful method, but it's a bit more complicated, especially if you don't have much experience with gimp of photoshop.